# SQL Server 2008 R2 backup fails to restore on SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, backup

My DR SQL Server got automatically updated by Windows update from 2008 R2 to 2008 R2 SP2 and since then I can't restore backups from my production machine which is still on 2008 R2.

> 10 percent processed.
> 20 percent processed.
>
> Msg 3183, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
> RESTORE detected an error on page (0:0) in database "si7500_1" as read from the backup set.
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

I can restore backups that were made prior to the DR update but not ones made since even though the production machine that made the backup hasn't changed. This makes me think that this is something other than the actual DB engine version that is wrong as I'd have expected all old backups to fail in that case.

I've tried removing the SP2 update but this makes no difference?

Anyone has any ideas on what to do as I'm reluctant to update my live server without a working DR backup.

Comment: Actually the problem isn't installing SP2 it install the update KB2977320 for SP2 which takes the engine version to 10.50.4033 from 4000. Both servers are already on SP2.

Comment: No this should not be problem with SQL Server after applying security update unless this is a bug, which I dont think. Now did you run restore verifyonly:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188902.aspx to chekc whether backup set is clean ? How far is your DR from PR ?

Comment: Sorry forgot to ask what is the backup size. Is your network reliable to transfer huge data ?

Comment: Hi Shanky,Should have said the bak files are copied over a wan link - the db is only 7GB so not too hard to do. Its concievable thought that someone went screwy in the network. I'll recopy an older one over and see if it then fails.

Comment: I don't have the old file anymore but I've MD5'd the new ones and they are indeed different. The small transaction files are fine so it looks like we have a problem copying large files. Thanks for the clue.

Comment: I was reading and found this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2010/05/10/how-to-copy-very-large-files-across-a-slow-or-unreliable-network.aspx will surely be helpful